# solving least square for matrix instead of vector

Tags: matlab, scipy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, least-squares

The problem is to find Z such that epsilon(E) (equation 21) is minimized.

Z is an MxN matrix which is what we need to find. Zx and Zy are also MxN matrix which are also known already. Dx and Dy are NxN matrix that carry out numerical differentiation (see the matrix circled in red in the photo), so they are also known matrix. F denotes the 'Fobrenius norm', or the 'entry-wise norm'.

How to solve this problem? I know how to solve least square problem for a vector, but now it is in matrix form and I get stuck.
thanks 
[image]

Comment: In principle it should be possible to formulate the problem as an unrestricted optimization problem over the components of `z_ij`

Comment: Unroll `Z` into a single vector, solve for that vector then reshape it back into a matrix.

Comment: I tried to solve a similar problem before in which I make Z is single vector. Problem is that it takes a very very long time to solve, and I run into memory problems M*N is greater than 10000. So I'm wondering if there are some special algorithms to solve it (like in matrix form) that are more efficient

Comment: To solve a least square problem, should the matrix not be a tall matrix? i.e. with more rows then columns. However, here you have 5 rows and 5 columns!

Comment: D_y*Z is an M x N matrix so D_y has to be MxM, yes? Are D_x and D_y related?

Comment: Both Dx and Dy carry out differentiation, so they are essentially the same except they have different size. Dx is NxN and Dy is MxM

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

$$
\begin{align*}
{\left| \boldsymbol{D}*{y} \boldsymbol{Z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{Z}}*{y} \right|}*{F}^{2} & \rightarrow {\left| \left( \boldsymbol{I} \otimes \boldsymbol{D}*{y} \right) \boldsymbol{z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}*{y} \right|}*{2}^{2} = {\left| \hat{\boldsymbol{D}*{y}} \boldsymbol{z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}*{y} \right|}*{2}^{2} \
{\left| \boldsymbol{Z} \boldsymbol{D}*{x}^{T} - \hat{\boldsymbol{Z}}*{x} \right|}*{F}^{2} & \rightarrow {\left| \left( \boldsymbol{D}*{x} \otimes \boldsymbol{I} \right) \boldsymbol{z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}*{x} \right|}*{2}^{2} = {\left| \hat{\boldsymbol{D}*{x}} \boldsymbol{z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{z}}*{x} \right|}*{2}^{2}
\end{align*}
$$

[image]

Which is equivalent to solve:

$$
{\left| \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{z} - \hat{\boldsymbol{z}} \right|}_{2}^{2}
$$

[image]

Where the matrix $\boldsymbol{D}$ is by stacking the matrices horizontally and $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}$ is by stacking vertically.

The implementation should take advantage of the sparse property of the relevant matrices so computation wise all is as efficient as the original formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

```
    normF(A*Z-B)^2=trace((A*Z-B).T*(A*Z-B))
```

so that for a directional derivative in direction dZ you get

```
    2*trace((A*dZ).T*(A*Z-B))=dotF(dZ,A.T*(A*Z-B))
```

This usually gets interpreted that the derivative is `A.T*(A*Z-B)`.

In the other term you get similarly,

```
    normF(Z*A.T-B.T)^2 = trace((A*Z.T-B)*(Z*A.T-B.T))
```

with directional derivative

```
    2*trace(A*dZ.T*(Z*A.T-B.T))=dotF(dZ,(Z*A.T-B.T)*A)
```

Adding `x` and `y` to the matrix names gives in the sum the derivative

```
    2*Z*(Ax.T*Ax) + 2*(Ay.T*Ay)*Z - 2*Bx.T*Ax - 2*Ay.T*By
```

an equation of the form

```
    Z*Qx + Qy*Z = C
```

Now take the diagonalizations `Q=U*D*U.T` with orthogonal `U` and diagonal `D`, multiply left by `Uy.T`, right by `Ux` to get

```
(Uy.T*Z*Ux)*Dx + Dy*(Uy.T*Z*U) = (Uy.T*C*Ux)
```

and one can read off the solution algorithm. Elementwise compute `(Uy.T*Z*Ux)`, then obtain `Z` by matrix multiplications.